# What is special about remastering (compared to regular mastering)?

Tags: mastering, remastering

What are the typical circumstances and steps involved in remastering?

I'm thinking about things such as origin of program material, types of processing and perhaps things that are special in remastering compared to regular mastering.

Comment: As far as I've seen, "remastering" just means making a new master from the original mix. "Digitally remastered" means they went to the original mix and mastered it again for CD, which pretty much had to be done 100% of the time since the cassette tape master wouldn't be very good for CD and the LP master would be mostly unusable for CD.

Comment: Okay so it is a requirement that you work on the original mix and not a previous mastering (the latter may be all that exist)? Btw how come you post your answers as comments?

Comment: Since I did not discuss the "circumstances and steps involved in remastering", I did not consider my comment to be an answer to your question. I don't know if remasters have been or are frequently made from another master or if they are always made from the original mix. I doubt a very good CD master could be made from an LP master, since LP masters have so many required processes that would be hard to "undo" to make the CD master sound good. Also note that I posted an answer, not a comment, to your other question from today.

Comment: Okay, true - well I think your information here qualifies as an answer ;-) What really motivates this question here is if people actually worked with remastering from an existing master/release - which of course is inoptimal, but then again it may be all there is to work with..